# Index Signature for manipulating objects

Tags: typescript

If I want to manipulate an object, or an array of objects, do I have to setup the interface like this?

```
interface Products {
  [key: string]: string | number;
}
```

I've noticed that if I have a fixed set of properties, typescript complains about a missing property.  For example If I try to add a property, it complains that it doesn't exist and I cannot add it to the object

Initial Interface

```
interface Products {
  id: string;
  price: number;
  description: string;
}
```

Somewhere in my script I add the `quantity` to the object and I want the output to be:

```
{ id: "123abc", price: 5, description: "Large Ball", quantity: 1 };
```

Comment: Perhaps you are just looking for [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) of the form `{ quantity?: number }`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYJkvw)?  If that doesn't work for your use case you might want to be more explicit about what you mean by "manipulating objects".

Comment: @jcalz by manipulating I want to be able to add properties to my output from an incoming API response that has the interface  "Initial Interface" I showed above.

Comment: Are the properties to add completely arbitrary/dynamic or do you know ahead of time which ones they will be?  Can you tell me whether or not optional properties as linked [here](https://tsplay.dev/WYJkvw) work for your use case?

Comment: If you really need to evolve the type of an object over time by adding properties you could leverage [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nn6aaN), but that's probably overkill for what looks at first glance like a straightforward use case for optional properties.

Comment: No the properties are not completely arbitrary/dynamic, I do know what most of them will be beforehand and yes the optional properties worked.

Comment: Is using index signature not a viable option here?

Comment: It's viable, but intended for situations where you truly have no idea which property keys may be present on the object and you just want to say "for any property which is on the object, the value is assignable to (say) `string | number`".  Using an index signature means, among other things, that `someProduct.quantity` will be given the type `string | number` even though you know it's `number`.  If you have more specific information, you should probably use it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to declare the possibility, that additional parameters are an option. There are several ways to tackle your problem. In your example i would recommend using [records](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) and replacing your mapped type like this:

```
Record<string, string | number>
```

and then use [type intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) to combine your two types like this:

```
interface ProductBasics {
  id: string;
  price: number;
  description: string;
}

type Products = ProductBasics & Record<string, string | number>
```

Now you can put an arbitrary amount of keys into your object, that are either string or number, but also benefit from the explicit types for the keys id, price and description.

If you want a fixed amount of additional keys [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) may could help:

```
interface Product {
  id: string;
  price: number;
  description: string;
  quantity?: number;
}
```

Comment: You might want to correct "optional parameters" to "optional properties" and provide a [documentation link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties).  Also, `quantity?: number` is not merely syntax sugar for `quantity: number | undefined`.  The former allows you to omit the `quantity` property while the latter does not. ([demo](https://tsplay.dev/WkvG0m))

Comment: I was quite sure it was equivalent, but apparently its not. Thanks.

Comment: @MircoS. - well, this stems from the fact that `{ a: undefined, b:1 }` and `{ b:1 }` are not equivalent. The semantics is different (for example, `a` is enumerable). TypeScript justly reflects that difference.